# How to programmatically update/create wordpress menu from agiven list of categories?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am writing a small wordpress plugin that would read a list of WooCommerce product categories and then create a menu or update an existing menu as per the category names and links. The update is triggered by clicking a button in a POSTed form. So far the plugin creates the menu with all categories and sub categories as parent items in the menu, I want it to put sub categories into sub menus but it fails.

Here is the code that helps me achieve this:

```
public function update_menu(){
        $children  = array();
        $mains  = array();
        $no_menu = false;
        $args = array(
            'taxonomy'     => 'product_cat',
            'orderby'      => 'name'
        );

        $all_categories = get_categories( $args );
        $menu_name = get_option('woo_cats_menu_menu_name');
        $locations = get_nav_menu_locations();

        $menus = get_registered_nav_menus();
        foreach ( $menus as $name => $description ){
            if ( $menu_name == $name )
                $menu_description = $description;
        }

        if ( !empty ( $all_categories ) ){
            //public variables defined in the class
            $this->added = 0;
            $this->notadded = 0;
            $this->notinmenu = 0;
            $this->inmenu = 0;

            $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object($locations[$menu_name]);
            $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id); //convert to array

            $menu_items = $this->toArray( $menu_items );
            echo "<br><br>Menus printouts.. Converted to array<br />";
            print_r( $menu_items );
            foreach ($all_categories as $cat) {
                if (!empty( $locations ) && isset($locations[$menu_name]) ) {


                    //if the category is not in the menu, then we add it//
                    //if ($cat->name != $title && get_term_link($cat->slug, 'product_cat') != $url && )
                    if ( false == $this->in_multiarray($cat->name, $menu_items) ){//!$this->in_array_md( $cat->name, $menu_items)
                        if ( $cat->parent == 0 || $cat->parent == "" || $cat->category_parent == 0 ){ //if is a main category
                            $mains[]    =   array(
                                'cat_id'            => $cat->term_id,
                                'name'              => $cat->name,
                                'cat_name'          => $cat->cat_name,
                                'slug'              => $cat->slug,
                                'category_parent'   => $cat->category_parent,
                                'link'              => get_term_link($cat->slug, 'product_cat')
                            );
                        }else{ // if child_of is > 0
                            $children[] = array(
                                'cat_id'            => $cat->term_id,
                                'name'              => $cat->name,
                                'cat_name'          => $cat->cat_name,
                                'slug'              => $cat->slug,
                                'category_parent'   => $cat->category_parent,
                                'child_of'          => $cat->category_parent,
                                'link'              => get_term_link($cat->slug, 'product_cat')
                            );  
                        }
                        $this->notinmenu++;
                    }else{
                        $this->inmenu++;
                    }
                }else{
                    $no_menu = true;
                }
            }
        }
        /*echo "<br />Second printout<br />";
        print_r( $menu_items );*/
        if ( $no_menu == false && !empty( $mains ) ){
            echo "<br /><strong>Adding main categories</strong><br />";
            /*print_r( $mains );
            echo "<br />End: Mains<br />";*/

            if ( count( $mains ) > 1 ){
                //if we have multiple categories
                foreach ( $mains as $main ){                    
                    //print_r ( $main );
                    if ( !$this->in_multiarray($main['name'], $menu_items) ){ //if is a main category
                        echo "Category not in menu...., ";
                        echo "Adding to menu::> '".$main['name']."' = '".$main['link'] . "'<br />";/**/
                        $menu_id = wp_update_nav_menu_item($menu->term_id, 0, array(
                            'menu-item-title'   => esc_attr( $main['name'] ),
                            'menu-item-url'     => esc_attr( $main['link'] ), 
                            'menu-item-status'  => 'publish')
                        );
                        if ( !is_wp_error($menu_id) ) $this->added++;
                        else $this->notadded++;
                    }else{
                        $this->notadded++;  
                    }
                }
            }elseif ( count ( $mains ) == 0 ){
                //if we have one category, call it mains
                $main = $mains;
                if ( !$this->in_multiarray($main['name'], $menu_items) ){ //if is a sub category
                    echo "Category not in menu...., ";
                    echo "Adding to menu::> '".$main['name']."' = '".$main['link'] . "'<br />";/**/
                    $menu_id = wp_update_nav_menu_item($menu->term_id, 0, array(
                        'menu-item-title'   => esc_attr( $main['name'] ),
                        'menu-item-url'     => esc_attr( $main['link'] ), 
                        'menu-item-status'  => 'publish')
                    );
                    if ( !is_wp_error($menu_id) ) $this->added++;
                    else $this->notadded++;
                }else{
                    $this->notadded++;  
                }
            }else{
                $this->notadded++;
            }
        }

        if ( $no_menu == false && !empty( $children ) ){
            echo "<br /><strong>Adding child menu items.</strong><br />";
            if ( count ( $children ) > 1 ) {
                foreach ( $children as $child ){
                    if ( !$this->in_multiarray($child['name'], $menu_items) ){//!$this->in_array_md( $child['name'], $menu_items, false)
                        echo "-- Adding Sub Category:: ID: " . $child['cat_id'].", parent: ". $child['category_parent'].", Name: ".$child['name'].", -> \"".$child['link']."\"<br />";/**/

                        $parent_id = esc_attr( $this->get_parent_id( $mains, $children, esc_attr( $child['cat_id'] ) ) );
                        $parent_name = $this->get_parent_name( $mains, $parent_id );
                        $menu_item = $this->get_menu_item( $parent_name, $child['link'] );
                        //print_r ( $menu_item );

                        echo "Real Parent: $parent_name, {$menu_item->ID}<br />";
                        $menu_id = wp_update_nav_menu_item($menu->term_id, 0, array(
                            'menu-item-title'       => esc_attr( $child['name'] ),
                            'menu-item-parent-id'   => $menu_item->ID,
                            'menu-item-url'         => esc_attr( $child['link'] ), 
                            'menu-item-status'      => 'publish')
                        );
                        //echo  $sub_category->name ;
                        //update post_parent 
                        if ( !is_wp_error($menu_id) ) {
                            wp_update_post(array('ID'=>$menu_id,'post_parent'=>$menu_item->ID));
                            update_post_meta( $menu_id, '_menu_item_menu_item_parent', $menu_item->ID );
                            $this->added++;
                        }
                        else $this->notadded++;
                    }else{
                        $this->notadded++;  
                    }
                }
            }elseif ( count ( $children ) == 1 ) {
                if ( false == $this->in_multiarray($child['name'], $menu_items)  ){//!$this->in_array_md( $child['name'], $menu_items, false)
                    echo "-- Adding Sub Category:: ".$child['name'].", -> \"".$child['link']."\"<br />";/**/
                    //$parent_id = esc_attr( $this->get_parent_id( $mains, $children, esc_attr( $child['cat_id'] ) ) );
                    $parent_id = esc_attr( $this->get_parent_id( $mains, $children, esc_attr( $child['cat_id'] ) ) );
                    $parent_name = $this->get_parent_name( $mains, $parent_id );
                    $menu_item = $this->get_menu_item( $parent_name, $child['link'] );

                    echo "Real Parent: $parent_name, {$menu_item->ID}<br />";
                    $menu_id = wp_update_nav_menu_item($menu->term_id, 0, array(
                        'menu-item-title'       => esc_attr( $child['name'] ),
                        'menu-item-parent-id'   => $menu_item->ID,
                        'menu-item-url'         => esc_attr( $child['link'] ), 
                        'menu-item-status'      => 'publish')
                    );

                    //echo  $sub_category->name ;
                    //update post_parent
                    if ( !is_wp_error($menu_id) ) {
                        wp_update_post(array('ID'=>$menu_id,'post_parent'=>$menu_item->ID));
                        update_post_meta( $menu_id, '_menu_item_menu_item_parent', $menu_item->ID );
                        $this->added++;
                    }
                    else $this->notadded++;
                }else{
                    $this->notadded++;  
                }
            }else{
                $this->notadded++;  
            }
        }
        /*echo "<br>Mains<br>";
        print_r( $mains );
        echo "<br>Children<br>";
        print_r( $children );*/

        //if we have updated a menu
        if ( $no_menu == true ){
            echo '<div class="alert alert-warning settings-error notice update-nag"><p><strong>Sorry but nothing to do!</strong> Please make sure you created an empty menu and assign it to the menu <em><strong>"'.$menu_description.'"</strong></em> selected on the right. Go to <em><strong>"Appearance > Menus"</strong></em>, select the menu you selected on this page and check the checkbox next to <em><strong>"'.$menu_description.'"</strong></em>.</p></div>';
        }else{
            echo '<div class="updated alert alert-success"><p><strong>The menu has been updated!</strong> ' . $this->notinmenu . ' Items were added to the menu, '. $this->inmenu .' Items were already in the menu.</p></div>';    
        }
    }

    public function get_parent_id( $parents, $children, $kid ){
        foreach ( $parents as $parent ){
            foreach ( $children as $child ){
                if ( $parent['cat_id'] == $child['child_of'] && $child['cat_id'] == $kid ){
                    return $parent['cat_id'];
                }
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public function get_parent_name( $parents, $parent_id ){
        foreach ( $parents as $parent ){
            if ( $parent['cat_id'] == $parent_id ){
                return $parent['name'];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public function get_menu_item($menu_item_name, $link){
        global $wpdb;
        $table = $wpdb->prefix.'posts';

        $post = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM {$table} WHERE post_title='{$menu_item_name}' AND post_type='nav_menu_item'"); // url='{$link}'");
        return $post;
    }

public function in_multiarray($elem, $array){
   //checks if $elem is in multidimensional $array
}
```